# how to import csv file using feed import module

Tags: importing-exporting

I am using feed import module . But i do not know how to import the csv file. can anyone explain how to import the csv file using this feed import module

Answer (score 1):

Feeds module allow you to import data with csv file.You can follow the following steps to import your csv content and convert them to individual nodes.

- After installing the Feeds module , open the feeds admin panel. `Admin menu -> Structure -> Feeds Importers`
- There you will see Add Importer link.Click on that.
- Provide a name and description for the importer.Name can be anything that represent your cause of creating a feed importer.

[image]

- Then Click on the basic settings link.In the section `Attach to content type` select the content type in which you want to feed the data.Then `Periodic import`, here choose `As often as possible` or depending upon your need.

[image]
 - Click on `fetcher change` and select the `File Upload` option as we are uploading our csv file.

[image]
 - Then Click on `Parser` and select `CSV parser` since we are parsing a csv file.

[image]

- Leave `Processor` as such .
- Click on `Node processor`.In the `Bundle` dropdown,select the content type you want to import the feeds data to. ( If you have not created a content type, you will be require to create one that matches with the csv content). Leave other option as such.

[image]

- Click on the `mapping` Link now.This is the most important of all steps .It maps your csv columns with the content type field that you have created for importing the data.Carefully type the name of csv columns on teh left section and then selct the respective field name from the drop down in the right section.

[image]

Example Mapping settings

[image]

`Always save at every stage`

Answer (score 0):

**Run the import:**

- Navigate to Structure -> Feeds Importer, and click on the "import"
  link.
- Click on the Bulk File Upload link.
- Upload your CSV file into your sites/default/files folder.
- Upload your import-upload folder, containing all the files to be
  imported into your Drupal root.
- Enter your CSV file's name in the File text field, with a the word
  "public://" prepended. So the entry should be something like
  "public://bulk_import.csv".
- Click on the Import Button.

More [Details](https://www.isovera.com/blog/using-feeds-module-bulk-import-drupal-7)